# Iteración de una función de una variable fija en relación a múltiples variables en R

Tags: r, bucles

Deseo aplicar una función que tome los valores de A e itere sobre los valores de las demás variables (B, C, D), por ejemplo realizar una correlación de A con B, y una de A con C y una de A con D, sin necesidad de aplicar algo como:

```
datos = data.frame(A = c(1,7,8,5),
                   B= c(9,6,5,6),
                   C= C(8,2,7,5),
                   D= c(50,75,25,80)


cor(datos$A~datos$B)
cor(datos$A~datos$C)
cor(datos$A~datos$D

Gracias.
```

Answer (score 1):

Con tus datos:

```
datos <- data.frame(A = c(1,7,8,5),
                    B = c(9,6,5,6),
                    C = c(8,2,7,5),
                    D = c(50,75,25,80))
```

Puedes aplicar `cor()` sobre el `data.frame` completo, esto generará una matriz de correlación entre cada una de las variables:

```
           A           B          C           D
A  1.0000000 -0.96358830 -0.5087231 -0.13814942
B -0.9635883  1.00000000  0.4364358  0.07597372
C -0.5087231  0.43643578  1.0000000 -0.69631062
D -0.1381494  0.07597372 -0.6963106  1.00000000
```

Si quieres solo las correlaciones de las variable con `A` puedes quedarte con la primer fila o columna, por ejemplo:

```
cor(datos)[1, -1]

         B          C          D 
-0.9635883 -0.5087231 -0.1381494
```

Answer (score 0):

Uso el dataset penguins, pero puedes usar tu data.frame y funciona igual. Simplemente cambia en mi código el nombre de mi data.frame ***df*** por el nombre de tu data.frame ***datos***.

Si deseas usar la función cor, puedes usar la primera parte, pero te agrego otras opciones relacionadas con el tema. Las dos últimas aparecen en la sección de plots y pueden guardarse como imagen o pdf.

```
library(tidyverse)

library(palmerpenguins)

data(penguins)

df = penguins 

# Primera Opción
df %>% select(where(is.numeric)) %>% cor(use = "complete.obs")

# Segunda Opción
library(modelsummary)
df %>% select(where(is.numeric)) %>% datasummary_correlation(use = "complete.obs")

# Tercera Opción
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
df %>% select(where(is.numeric)) %>% chart.Correlation(histogram = T, pch = 19)
```

[image: cor function]
[image: datasummary_correlation function]
[image: char.Correlation function]